# Compare two datatables to find matching values

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 data tables. Each one has one column and I want to compare them and get same values on them but it does not work.

This is my code:

```
string CurrentRequestUrl = (HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.ToString());
DataTable dt_Item = ERP.BLL_Menu_Item.Custom_Item_ID(CurrentRequestUrl);
DataTable dt2_SysRole = ERP.BLL_Sys_User_Role.Custom_Role(Convert.ToInt64(App.UserID));

var dtOne = (dt_Item.AsEnumerable()).ToList();
var dtTwo = (dt2_SysRole.AsEnumerable()).ToList();


IEnumerable<DataRow> objIntersectResult = ((dtOne).Intersect((dtTwo))).ToList();
```

How can I find the matching values?

Comment: You can use JOIN in linq for this

Comment: What does not work mean? Do you get an exception? wrong output? Only wrong output in certain conditions?

Comment: you comparing all record not just one column.

Comment: Which row of both tables do you want to take?

Comment: we need more info on what the problem is?

Comment: @TimSchmelter By definition doesn't this kind of task require checking _all_ rows?

Comment: @TylerH sure but if you found a match, do you want to select both rows or only a row from one of both tables?

Comment: @TimSchmelter D'oh, I must have misread "take" as "check" while looking through the comments over the weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Intersect` does not work here because on `DataRow` it just compares references. Because all rows are different references you get an empty list. Instead you want to compare values. Therefore you can use `Join`. But which row do you want to return from both tables? If you want both rows you could create an anonymous type of both:

```
var objJoinResult = from rowItem in dt_Item.AsEnumerable()
                    join rowSysRole in dt2_SysRole.AsEnumerable()
                    on rowItem.Field<string>("ColumnName") equals rowSysRole.Field<string>("ColumnName")
                    select new { rowItem, rowSysRole };
```

Output:

```
foreach (var both in objJoinResult)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("rowItem:{0} rowSysRole:{1}", 
        string.Join(",", both.rowItem.ItemArray),
        string.Join(",", both.rowSysRole.ItemArray));
}
```